# Chip on the door frame

Tags: wood, doors, frame, chip

Someone hit the door frame with the vacuum cleaner and caused a chip. It is made with solid material.
The door frame is in the bathroom area so the floor will be getting mopped frequently.

Is this an easy fix?

[image]

Comment: Can't see how it will get worse. Only way is if 'someone' keeps knocking the vac into it, in which case it'll need doing time and time again.

Answer (score 3):

That is MDF type. It is so weak it falls apart by just looking at it.

Option: Get solid wood framing.

Or repair the damage DIY style (for a cost of $5) knowing it is very sensitive to vacuum cleaners bumps.