# To replace the whole frame of just fill it in and paint it

Tags: door-frame, wood-filler

The painter came and gave two options. He said either he could fill in the damaged area of the frame or he could replace the whole frame. What are your thoughts? Is it worth replacing the whole frame for a small area?
[image]

It is about 2 cm long and the door frame is pretty standard  door.

Comment: Or this? [How do I fix a door frame that my dog chewed?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/4043/35141)

Comment: Or your [earlier question on the same topic](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/274459/chip-on-the-door-frame)?

Comment: "Worth it" is subjective and off topic. My two cents are that a proper replacement is a fairly extensive job considering the caulking, filling, and painting required and isn't warranted. A little smoothing putty and paint and forget about it.

Comment: Yes,  but I can replace with wood rather than MDF

Comment: I do find a nice stained or clear coating on wood looks nicer, but wood can also get damaged like MDF if someone hits it.  I save paint for drywall, MDF or cheap stuff.